# How do I resolve "array_merge argument is not an array"?

Tags: php, array-merge

I am receiving an error that indicates that:

> array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

I'm trying to resolve it but I'm not sure what else to try.  Here is the code that I an executing:

```
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = Application::getInstance()->request->getRootUri();
    $config['public_url'] = $config['base_url'] . '/public';
    $config['bower_components_url'] = $config['public_url'] . '/bower_components';

    $app_config = array();
    $app_config = require_once 'app/config/application.php';

    $full_config = array_merge($config, $app_config, $data);
```

Argument app config requires this file:

```
return array (

    'debug' => true,

    'app_name' => 'Name',

    'app_author' => 'Author',

    'app_url' => '',

    'session_prefix' => '',

    'session_secret' => '',

);
```

Can someone help me to understand why I am receiving this error?

Comment: `app/config/application.php` isn't this doable inside a function instead of being inside another php file?

Comment: Yes, but i preferred to keep it separate

Comment: Try to `var_dump($app_config)` after `$app_config = require_once ...`.

Comment: this is output: bool(true)

Comment: Made some grammar and formatting adjustments in addition to modifying the title slightly so that readers can identify what your issue is more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put php opening tag at the beginning of this config file:

```
<?php
return array (

    'debug' => true,

    'app_name' => 'Name',

    'app_author' => 'Author',

    'app_url' => '',

    'session_prefix' => '',

    'session_secret' => '',

);
```

Enable error reporting and check if your path is correct.

Comment: If the path is not correct then there is a different message and the script stops with a fatal error on the `require` statement (and `array_merge()` does not run at all).

Comment: the path is incorrect also when points to existing, but not necessarily this wanted file. Then there will not be fatal error.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are defining     $app_config  as array then redefining it as a variable. Try this

```
$app_config = array();
$app_config[] = require_once 'app/config/application.php';
```

Answer (score -1):

Doing this: `$app_config = require_once 'app/config/application.php';` will return an object (not an array for sure). I think.

I think this method is more customizable.

app/config/functions.php

```
//this will  be inside functions.php
function appConfig() {
    return array (
            'debug' => true,
            'app_name' => 'Name',
            'app_author' => 'Author',
            'app_url' => '',
            'session_prefix' => '',
            'session_secret' => '',
            );
}
```

Your main php file

```
require_once 'app/config/functions.php';

// your other code
$app_config = appConfig();

$full_config = array_merge($config, $app_config, $data);
```

Comment: If the execution of the included file completes because of a `return` statement, the value that is present in the `return` statement is the return value of the included file. The `include` language construct works like a function in this case. It's written in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php